# Can we use transaction scope for all methods in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

In my project, I have more than 50 methods. I don't want to write a transaction scope block for every method. It should be at the context level and there should be one option to disable or enable to use transaction Scope for all actions.
I am using Entity Framework 6.2

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already? Maybe some pseudo code of what you would like (ideally)?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, and an *iffy* design. I mean, you shouldn't need to be writing a transaction scope for every block for every method, and you shouldn't need to be using flags to turn them on and off configurably. Although the question is specific i think this is too broad. maybe you can put in some sample code and some use cases.

Comment: Why do you need a transaction scope in the first place? EF performs all operations in a call to `SaveChanges()` in a single transaction anyway.